# Перенос базы с SQL Server 2008 на 2019, несовместимость формата даты при обращении из Java

Tags: java, sql-server

Перенесли базу данных с SQL Server 2008 на SQL Server 2019
Все приложения, написанные на Java, которые обращаются к БД - выдают ошибку при использовании даты формата '2021-01-22 00:00:00.0'

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Ошибка при преобразовании типа данных varchar к datetime

При использовании даты формата '2021-01-22T00:00:00.0' - все ок.
Можно ли как-то настроить формат даты на SQL Server, чтобы не переписывать все программы под новый формат? Совместимость с 2008 сервером включена в настройках БД.

Comment: Может приведете примеры кода? Понятно что проблема общая и нужно решить ее настройками, но для полноты картины хотелось бы увидеть код на Java  (хотя бы один пример) и описание обращения к БД (как выполняется запрос, какого типа поля, почему varchar)? Возможно, этот поможет отвечающим.

Comment: могу предположить что такой формат обусловлен разными локалями SQL.